# Definitions of recurrence / transience (Discrete-time Markov Chains)

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains

We have that the definition of state $i$ being transient is $\mathbb{P}(\text{# times we are at $i$ is finite})=1$. Is this equivalent to saying $\mathbb{P}(\text{the first time step we return to $i$ is } \infty)>0$?

Also is it true that if $\mathbb{P}(\text{the first time step we return to $i$ is }<\infty)=1$, then state $i$ is recurrent?

Comment: Question is confusing.  Transient simply means no. recurrences is finite.  First recurrence is irrelevant.

Comment: The answer to your second question: yes. The answer to you first question: your question is kind of odd. The first time step we return to $i$ is $\infty$? Sort of odd, but it seems like you have the right intuition about it. But if you want to talk about the expectation of the first return time step, then you can be a little bit more well-defined.

Comment: @jeremy909 maybe I could have worded It better. I'm essentially asking if the probability that when we start in $i$ we may never return to $i$ is a probability greater than $0$, is this the same as saying that the number of visits to $i$ in infinite time is finite?